# Change Openstack Instance's Image

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

When creating an instance on openstack, it is automatically assigned an IP address on the subnet.

I have an instance that has a bad image. The network is configured for the given IP address.

Is there a way to change the image of an instance?  I have tried rebuilding but the bad image is still there.

Thanks

I tried running the following:

`nova --debug boot --flavor 17172145-c56e-4407-8f6b-5273fa19634d --image 41618691-aa09-4cf1-90ba-fdb4a742da87 --access-ip-v4 10.105.5.81 --access-ip-v6 10.105.5.81 --security-groups http_access TestingBoot`

To get the following error messages returned:

`DEBUG (shell:984) Not found (HTTP 404)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/shell.py", line 982, in main
    OpenStackComputeShell().main(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/shell.py", line 909, in main
    args.func(self.cs, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v2/shell.py", line 686, in do_boot
    boot_args, boot_kwargs = _boot(cs, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v2/shell.py", line 281, in _boot
    image = _find_image(cs, args.image)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v2/shell.py", line 2350, in _find_image
    raise exceptions.CommandError(six.text_type(e))
CommandError: Not found (HTTP 404)
ERROR (CommandError): Not found (HTTP 404)`

I also found another error further"up" the debug log:

`RESP BODY: 404 Not Found`

`The resource could not be found.`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the current instance and create a new instance with the same ip address. For example, you can use command:

```
nova boot \
  --flavor <FLAVOR-ID> \
  --image <IMAGE-ID> \
  --nic net-id=<NET-ID>,v4-fixed-ip=<IP-ADDR>,v6-fixed-ip=<IP-ADDR> \
  <NAME>
```

Comment: I tried that and got the following error: ERROR (CommandError): Not found (HTTP 404)

Comment: Provide more information. What is it not found? What is the command are you ran? What exactly message are you receive? Check openstack log files.

Comment: Please pass --debug to your command and post those logs - be sure to sanitize them if necessary.

Comment: @e42d3 The debug output is in the second half of the original post. I did not post ALL of the the debug output, just what looked like errors.

Comment: @andyhky The debug output is in the second half of the original post. I did not post ALL of the the debug output, just what looked like errors.

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v2/shell.py", line 2350, in _find_image
    raise exceptions.CommandError(six.text_type(e)) Image not found. Please upload new image and try create instance.

Comment: without the full debug logs, it may be difficult to determine the problem. does image 41618691-aa09-4cf1-90ba-fdb4a742da87 show when you do an image-show ?

Answer (score 0):

try nova-rebuild http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/nova.html with an image id that shows up from image-list.

Comment: Ran into the same issue as the other fix: ` ERROR (CommandError): Not found (HTTP 404)`